# How to create Base Class Object from Child Class Object

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

I have two classes. One is Base class which is inherited in Child class.

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Manager : Employee
{
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
    public Employee GetEmployee()
    {
        // return employee object.
    }
}
```

Now, I need to get `Employee` class object through `Manager` class object.

```
Manager manager = new Manager();
manager.FirstName = "A";
manager.LastName = "B";
manager.Salary = 25000;

Employee employee = manager.GetEmployee();
```

I am not sure, if this is possible but i don't want to assign particular property one by one.

Please suggest better option.

Comment: u can use a constructor

Comment: You already have Employee Properties accessible through Manager object there is no separate Employee object in Manager.

Answer (score 2):

`Manager` is an `Employee`, so you can simply return `this`:

```
public Employee GetEmployee()
{
    return this;
}
```

It is not entirely clear what is the purpose of the method `GetEmployee`, because you can use `Manager` everywhere you need `Employee`:

```
public void SomeMethodThatAcceptsEmployee(Employee emp)
{
}

Employee employee = new Employee();
Manager manager = new Manager();

// You can call this method passing Employee:
SomeMethodThatAcceptsEmployee(employee);
// But you can also call this method passing Manager:
SomeMethodThatAcceptsEmployee(manager);
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have the `Employee` object with the `Manager` object. If, for example, you have a method printing the full name of an employee, such as

```
void PrintFullName(Employee e)
{
  Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", e.FirstName, e.LastName));
}
```

you can simply call this function with a manager object, such as

```
Manager m = new Manager();
m.FirstName = "M";
m.LastName = "S";
m.Salary = 10000;
PrintFullName(m);
```

Basic inheritance, I don't see why you'd need a `GetEmployee` method.

Comment: I need Employee Object because i have another project where just Employee class is accessible not Manager class and need to pass that Employee object in a method of that project.

Comment: @user2878759 a `Manager` is an `Employee`. What you are asking for would be needed if you were not using inheritance, but any function that takes an `Employee` can be passed a `Manager` object.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add a method to the Manager class, you can just cast it with the as operator if you need to get a direct Employee type reference without the manager properties.

```
var employee = manager as Employee;
```

Or if you have a function

```
public void DoStuff(Employee employee)
{
}
```

You can just call it with

```
DoStuff(new Manager())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the generic way using reflection

```
public class Employee
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Manager : Employee
    {
        public decimal Salary { get; set; }
        public T GetEmployee<T>()
        {
            var emp = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
            var properties = emp.GetType().GetProperties();
            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                property.SetValue(emp, property.GetValue(this));
            }
            return emp;
        }
    }
```

call it using

```
Employee employee = manager.GetEmployee<Employee>();
```

Comment: sure it will, it's reflection and it's generic :)

Comment: Although technically correct, I cannot see a situation where this makes sense? But I may miss something in the question.

Comment: OP said- I need Employee Object because i have another project where just Employee class is accessible not Manager class and need to pass that Employee object in a method of that project.